# Apache wicket: Componenet.replaceWith(component) from Linktree.onNodeSelected()

Tags: wicket

I have a linktree for navigation over data which shall replace a component in another div.

For this in the tree I have the treestatelistener implementing

```
public void nodeSelected(Object node) {
    log.debug("nodeSelected: " + node+ " class: " + node.getClass());
            Component content = new Label("content");
            content.replaceWith(new Label("content", "Hello World"));
        }
    }
}
```

All I get is the message:

> "This method can only be called on a component that has already been
>   added to its parent."

The Label with Id "content" is added to the page on init, so it is there before. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always have issues with just calling Component.replaceWith(). Since I am doing this with AJAX, I always need to call a target.add().

My solution is for now to have a class MyTree extend LinkTree and in that class override the newNodeComponent().

Since in my application everything happens on the IndexPage.class and there I just replace components, I added a method handleSelection() to the IndexPage.Class(extends BasePage extends webpage). There I decide, based on the clicked nodeObject, how to replace a component in the IndexPage

```
Public Class MyTree extends Linktree{
  protected Component newNodeComponent(String id, IModel<Object> model) {
  @Override
        protected void onNodeLinkClicked(Object node, BaseTree tree, AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            super.onNodeLinkClicked(node, tree, target);
            ((IndexPage)getPage()).handleSelection(target, (TreeNode)node);
        }

        @Override
        protected ResourceReference getResourceFolderOpen(Object node) {
            return getResourceForNode(node);
        }

        @Override
        protected ResourceReference getResourceFolderClosed(Object node) {
            return getResourceForNode(node);
        }

        @Override
        protected ResourceReference getResourceItemLeaf(Object node) {
            return super.getResourceItemLeaf(node);
        }

        @Override
        protected ResourceReference getImageResourceReference(BaseTree tree, Object node) {
            return getResourceForNode(node);
        }
  } 
}
```

I hope this is explained propperly, else: questions or comments wanted!

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new parent Component every time your treenode listener is called, without adding the 'content' label.
What I would suggest is to try something like this -

```
public MyPage extends WebPage {
  private Component parent = new WebMarkupContainer("parent");

  public WebPage() {
    parent.add(new Label("content", "hi");
  }
  ...
  public void nodeSelected(Object node) {
    log.debug("nodeSelected: " + node+ " class: " + node.getClass());
        parent.replaceWith(new Label("content", "Hello World"));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm. Where's that nodeselected comming from?

Comment: Regarding to line where you call replaceWith:
"Replacement component must have the same id as the component it will replace"
So as far as i see, the replaceWith function should be called on on the new Label you initialize in constructor.
Also as i remember after you call replace with you have to do: originalLabel = newLabel as well.
Whatever, i am using Wicket 6.20, just to make sure, we are talking about the same situation. :)